# Is it important to write database name before table name?

Tags: mysql

I have a database named `DELTASTORE` in mysql in my cpanel. There are tables like `ADMIN,CATAGORY,PRODUCT,ORDER`. I have inserted some values in each table.
 
If I run sql

```
SELECT * FROM ADMIN
```

it works nicely.
But if I run sql

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER
```

it doesn't work! Instead of that, if I run sql

```
SELECT * FROM DELTASTORE.ORDER
```

then it works correctly.
Why does that occur?
Is it important to write database name before table name and give a dot between them all the time?

Comment: Maybe, because `ORDER` is a keyword in SQL. (`ORDER BY`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To leave out the database prefix, you have to set a default database, with

```
USE databasename
```

When writing programs to access the database, the API provides a way to do this. For instance, in PHP PDO you specify the default database in the DSN:

```
mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDB
```

In MySQLi it's an argument to `mysqli_connect()`. In the obsolete mysql extension you use `mysql_use_database()`. There are similar methods in other programming languages.

Additionally, since `ORDER` is a MySQL keyword, you either have to put it in backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM `ORDER`
```

or prefix it with a database:

```
SELECT * FROM DELTASTORE.ORDER
```

It's usually best to avoid using MySQL reserved words as table or column names, to prevent problems like this. See [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql/23446378#23446378)

Comment: in my wamp server set up as a local server in my lapptop, i hava to write database name before table name every time i run a query. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: You need to use `USE databasename` to set the default database.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that ORDER is a SQL keyword (for ORDER BY, which you use to sort the result lines). So with the database name (or schematic name) you mean the table ORDER.
It's better to not use keywords for the table.

Answer (score -1):

Just need to put brackets.

`` Select * from `ORDER` ``

Comment: not working!   now  neither Select * from [ORDER] nor  Select * from [ADMIN]  worked!

Comment: Brackets are for SQL-Server. MySQL uses backticks.